# How to bind gender in dropdown in reactjs using c# api

Tags: reactjs

i need gender values in Dropdown options using third party API Axios in Reactjs.

Comment: What is the api response format?

Comment: its in json format

Answer (score 0):

I use `componentDidMount()` lifecycle event to execute `axios.get()` and set my state eg:

```
   state = {
    genderList: []
}

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(API_URL).then(res => this.setState({ genderList: res.data.genderList))
}
```

Then rendering it is just a matter of mapping the values in JSX:

```
<select
className="select"
onChange={this.handleChange}
name="gender">
{this.state.genderList.map(gender => (
    <option
        key={gender.id}
        value={gender.name}
    >
        {gender.name}
    </option>
))}
```

Comment: I am getting error below:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
PostForm.render
D:/ALL Projects Work/ReactJs/first-react-app/src/components/PostForm.js:111
  108 | </div>
  109 | <div>
  110 |     <label>Gender</label>
> 111 |     <select onChange={this.changeHandler} className='select' name='gender'>
      | ^  112 |         {this.state.genderList.map((gender, index) => (
  113 |             <option
  114 |                 key={gender.index}
View compiled

Comment: [
    {
        "iUserId": 168,
        "sUserLoginId": "pramod@gmail.com",
        "sUserName": null,
        "sFirstName": null,
        "sLastName": null,
        "sPassword": "Pramod@123",
        "sMobileNumber": "7666666666",
        "siGender": 1,
        "dtCreatedDate": "2019-10-01T15:23:01.107",
        "dtModifiedDate": "2019-10-01T15:35:10.737"
    }
]

Comment: If there is no `genderList` object in reply modify the `setState` to `res.data` and also make sure you are trying to read `iUserId` and `siGender` properties.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            siGender: [],
}
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:55901/api/User/GetUser')
            .then(response => { this.setState({ siGender: response.data.siGender }) })
    }
}
<select>{this.state.siGender.map(gender => (<option key={gender.value={gender.siGender}>{gender.siGender}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </select>